# Get updated changes files from Git in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control

My job in Jenkins get the origin of the source code from a Git repository.

This is an example of the structure of the repository:

```
/repository
   /project1
       /premium.txt
   /project2
       /supplement.txt
   /project3
       /regulator.txt
```

I need to get the changes updated by the job for example:

Commit f341ldin3:

```
/project1/premium.txt
```

Should you use some Git command or some plugin or parameter to configure it in Jenkins? What is recommended?

Comment: Jenkins has plugins for Git repositories, such as GitHub and Bitbucket.  Just search for this.  By the way, your question is probably a duplicate of something else.

Answer (score 3):

To get changed files from Jenkins build job, you can add a **Windows PowerShell** step to achieve.

The PowerShell scripts as below:

```
$files=$(git diff head~ --name-only)
echo $files
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [JENKINS Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) has a section "Branches to Build".

Simply add and push a new branch created on that commit, and you will be able to specify said branch (meaning that commit referenced by the branch HEAD) to be built by your job.